# My Jquery events are storing objects being passed to them

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, jquery-events

My jQuery click events are storing past objects being sent to them, rather than using the latest object being requested on the click. Is there a way in Javascript or jQuery to use the last object being past?

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    console.log();
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});

$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
    removeSkillButton(object);
    addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

Here is a example of what I mean.

User click's event 1 on #position1.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    console.log();
    removeSkillButton(Skill 1);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

User click's event 2 on #position1.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
    console.log();
    removeSkillButton(Skill 2);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

User click's event 3 on #position2.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    console.log();
    removeSkillButton(Skill 1);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

User click's event 4 on #position3.

```
$('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
    console.log();
    removeSkillButton(Skill 1);
    addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
    removeRadialSubMenu(); 
});
```

So rather than using the *last object* passed to it, its using the first object that was registered when the first event function fired. How do I get it to use the lastest object, rather than the first stored object when the event is triggered?

Edit: Here is a list of the entire function.

```
function radialSelector(object){
    var skillList;
     switch (object){
        case strike:
        skillList = [poisonstrike, bluntstrike, quickstrike];
        break;
        case poisonstrike:
        skillList = [venom, immunity, toxic];
        break;
        case bluntstrike:
        skillList = [eviscerate, bruteforce, revenge];
        break;
        case quickstrike:
        skillList = [nimblelance, whirlwind, backstab];
        break;
        case defend:
        skillList = [holdtheline, quickrecovery, repairarmor];
        break;
        case holdtheline:
        skillList = [stronghold, titan, heavyarmor];
        break;
        case quickrecovery:
        skillList = [impenetrable, untouchable, fortifiedarmor];
        break;
        case repairarmor:
        skillList = [stonewall, stout, unbreakablearmor];
        break;
        case cure:
        skillList = [cura, blessing, healingwind];  
        break;
        case debuff:
        skillList = [lowerstrength, lowerarmor, loweragility];
        break;
        default:
        console.log("radialSelector() has set its switch statement to default")
    }
    
    for (var i=0, l=skillList.length; i<l; i++) {
    radialSubMenuSkills("position"+(i+1), skillList[i]);
    }
    

    $('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position1', function(){
        console.log();
        removeSkillButton(object);
        addSkillButton(skillList[0]);
        removeRadialSubMenu(); 
    });
    
    $('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position2', function(){
        removeSkillButton(object);
        addSkillButton(skillList[1]);
        removeRadialSubMenu(); 
    });
    
    $('#upgradeSkillsBar').one('click', '#position3', function(){
        removeSkillButton(object);
        addSkillButton(skillList[2]);
        removeRadialSubMenu(); 
    });
    
}
```

And what is calling it:

```
function strikeSkill() {
    activeCheck();
    if (upgradeActive == true){
        radialSelector(strike);
    }   
    if (upgradeActive == false){
    HitCalc(player.cc, monster.cc);
    actor.expCounter(player.cc);
    actor.balanceCounter(player.cc, monster.cc);
    }
};
```

Comment: You are not showing the code where you are storing anything. Your post should have self contained code, but you have critical functions that you didn't show how they work. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: `HitCalc` is now undefined, don't just paste code, break down your problem into a self contained example. What debugging have you already done?